# Angular2 - Textarea validation how to force blur

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My form is submitted via the **Enter** key. The value of the **textarea** is null, since the focus is still on the **textarea**.

Is there a way to force blur on the **textarea**, or is there any more graceful approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `ngSubmit` directive to submit form. I'd prefer you to check validity of form before calling submit method of the form. Make sure you should have `required` attribute on the fields which are required before submit.

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="myForm.valid && submit()">
```

So basically before submitting form it will check validity of form, if yes then only it will call `submit` method.

**Edit**

You could also do check form validity from your angular component also inside `submit` method.

**HTML**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="&& submit()">
```

**Component**

```
submit(){
   if(this.myForm.valid){
      console.log('MyForm is valid');
      //do make ajax or call action to submit data to server
   }
   else {
      //here form is invalid
      console.log('MyForm is valid');
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Comment: @LukaŠilje what do you mean by "programmatic way"?

Comment: By programmatic I meant inside typescript, outside of html. it seems that myForm.valid is only a boolean inside code.

Comment: @LukaŠilje look at the updated code. will help you. Thanks

Comment: thank you! This made me realize that the problem was elsewhere. The textbox won't trigger the `(change)` event, so I made a workaround by submitting the `this.form.value[this.columnName]` for value

Answer (score 6):

To blur a DOM form element, use a local template variable in combination with @ViewChild to get an  "Angular wrapped" reference to the textarea.  Then use Renderer to blur, after unwrapping it with nativeElement:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form>
      <textarea #textArea [(ngModel)]="text" (keyup.enter)="submit()"></textarea>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  text = "";
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer) { console.clear(); }
  @ViewChild('textArea') textArea:ElementRef;
  submit() {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
      this.textArea.nativeElement, 'blur', []);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/000hWNGSX8S88u86YnHi?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 things here to validate before submit -

1) Create a function in your component that validates your textarea and call it in your submit function.
Like this --

```
onSubmit(){
    isTextAreaValid = this.validateTextArea();
    if(isTextAreaValid){
         //submit the data
    }
}
```

2) Or create a property named 'isTextAreaValid' to check, like this --

```
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit() && isTextAreaValid" #heroForm="ngForm">
```

3) Or do just like this --

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="heroForm.form.valid && onSubmit()">
```